# How to load up many images without using too much memory

Tags: performance, memory

When writing games, I am aware that images take up a lot of space. If one has a large graphical game, they don't want problems with memory, or to give players the message "Go buy a better computer to run this game". However, loading up images everytime one needs an image and discarding it is *very* slow. So if a programmer has a large graphical game, how can they draw many images without sacrificing performance/memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Use scaling; make images smaller, but still having enough to get the character around. Scaling an 80x80 in to a 60x60 saves a lot of space for five hundred images, seeing as each one will be 1/4th smaller, taking up virtually 1/4th of the space.

2.Use better compressed image formats; a BMP will save more time than JPEG, and is smaller.

3.Remove images that are no longer in a visible portion of the screen to save memory. In the 8 and 16-bit world this was mandatory, as having such tight memory and slow CPUs, on top of bank switching, made the process daunting to imagine for a C/Windows programmer these days.
To recover the removed image, save where it was to an 8-bit byte container, and re-load it based on these coordinates. You can't lose with this method.

4.**Don't** load up too many images at once; I know this one is tough to comprehend, but tons of images at once isn't absolutely vital. In fact, it's not vital at all for a beginner program (which you seem to be, no offensive if you aren't) and cutting out a few extra images here and there make a stretch, but the saved memory and speed will thank you. Working with 3-D models, lots of large data files, and rendering is memory tougher. When you get there then it's time to work smarter, but as for 2-D games like a platformer, RPG, etc., my last three prior paragraphs should do the justice for you.

Comment: 1) If something is 1/4th smaller, it will take up 1/4th _less_ space, or 3/4th of the original space. 2) BMPs can be uncompressed; also, in general there's a tradeoff between storage size and processing time (ie a table of contents in a book takes an extra page).

Comment: On the other hand, a 256x256 RGBA image is only 256kb; in an age when memory is measured in *gigabytes* one has to maintain a sense of proportion - is this something that's even worth worrying about in advance of anything else?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - correct on BMPS but not with respect to math IFF we're discussing 2D images - reducing the size of the X and Y dimensions by 1/4 will reduce the image pixel count to 56% of the original size :-)

Comment: If you're going to go for image compression DXT1 and DXT5 tend to be the best options, as they will stay compressed in GPU memory and often improve rendering performance too.